# How to add a new table to magento database

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am using magento 1.4.2.0 and i need to add a new table to my magento database,It is for some of my custom cms pages where i need to add data to database and need to fetch that data and show it in the cms pages.Please explain me step by step as i am very new to magento.

Answer (score 2):

you have to use a setup file in your module: check out [Alan Storm's comprehensive post](http://alanstorm.com/magento_setup_resources)

Answer (score 0):

Create table using magento module write following code in sql folder mysql4-install-1.0.0.php file.

```
$installer = $this;

$table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable($installer->getTable(''))

->addColumn('news_id',Varien_Db_Dbl_Table::INTEGER_TYPE,null,array('unsigned'=>true,'identity'=>true,'nullable'=>false,'primary'=>true),'Entity Id')

->addColumn('title',Varien_Db_Dbl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,255,array('nullable'=>true),'Title')

->addColumn('author',Varien_Db_Dbl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,63,array('nullable'=>true,'default'=>'null'),'Author')

->addColumn('content',Varien_Db_Dbl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,'2M',array('nullable'=>true,'default'=>'null'),'Content')

->addColumn('image',Varien_Db_Dbl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,null,array('nullable'=>true,'default'=>'null'),'News Image Media Path')

->addColumn('publised_at',Varien_Db_Dbl_Table::TYPE_DATE,null,array('nullable'=>true,'default'=>'null'),'Published Date')

->addColumn('created_at',Varien_Db_Dbl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,null,array('nullable'=>true,'default'=>'null'),'Creation Time')

->addIndex($installer->getIdxName($installer->getTable(''),array('publised_at'),Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_INDEX),array('publised_at'),array('type'=>Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_INDEX))->SetComment('News Item');

$installer->getConnection->createTable($table);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class InstallSchema implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface
{

    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $table = $setup->getConnection()
        ->newTable($setup->getTable('magento_pincode_pincode'))
        ->addColumn(
                    'pincode_id',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    [
                        'identity' => true,
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'primary'  => true,
                        'unsigned' => true
                    ],
                    'ID'
                )->addColumn(
                    'pincode',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false],
                    'Pincode'
                )->addColumn(
                    'status',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    255,
                    ['nullable' => false],
                    'Status'
                )->addColumn(
                    'created_at',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT],
                    'Created At'
                )->addColumn(
                    'updated_at',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT_UPDATE],
                    'Updated At');
            $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);

            $setup->endSetup();

    }
}
```

Comment: 1.create one setup folder in module

2.create installschema file in setup folder 

3.fire this command 
php bin/magento setup:upgrade


4.if table is not create after this command then 
open setup module folder 
show table like '%setup%';


5.if there entry find of our module then delete that entry 
delete from setup_module where module='Magento_CreateAPI';

6.againn upgrade
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

7.then check again table created or not